# Parrot OS install in Parallels on Mac

Tags: macos, unix, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I have been using VirtualBox for years to run Windows and many Linux distributions but recently I purchased the Parallels program and am currently porting over all my virtual boxes. All of them work flawlessly except [Parrot OS](https://www.parrotsec.org/) (Debian based) and I just can't figure out why. I install it perfectly fine but when I try to boot it it hangs at the message below:

[image: Parrot OS Hung]

I have tried *nomodeset*, upgrading, booting from live (which also doesn't seem to boot), reinstalling the X.Org LightDM packages, tried pretty much everything I could find on Google. Because of this I think it is something to do with the Parallels settings and how it handles the OS.

The Parallels settings I am using are as follows:

- 2 Processors
- 3 GB RAM
- 128 MB Graphics Memory
- 64 GB Storage

I also have "Isolate Linux from Mac" selected under security

If you have any idea of something to try that would be much appreciated (since it is Debian based, Debian based fixes may work).

Comment: why Kali linux tag ?Also your problem whould be move on Ask different in my opinion the problems coms from a simple misgufiguration of advance cpu extension or something like or maybe disk space... it's strange

Comment: Please add the Parallels version. BTW Parrot & VMware 8.5.10 runs flawlessly (at least in Live mode)...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

disconnect the virtual machine and make this configuration, in my work, I have the latest version of parallel. try this.

Note: the example print is with the Kurumin configuration but works with the parrotOS

Comment: Please try to answer in english

Comment: Heres an attempted translation from Google Translate: disconnect the virtual machine and make this configuration, in my work, I have the latest version of parallel. try this.

Note: the example print is with the Kurumin configuration but works with the parrotOS

Comment: Ask Different is an English site and as such all posts should be in English. Can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/327166/edit) your answer to convert it to English?

Comment: @Monomeeth Just did. Cant fix the images (obviously), leave that up to romero.